# change placeholder text from array

Tags: yii

I'm using the yii-user extension and i'm trying the add proper label to the 'placeholder' attribute. really new to Yii so still trying to get the grasp of things.

I've added the `attributeLabels()` method in the class in the **models** folder.

```
class RegistrationForm extends User {
       /**
     * Declares attribute labels.
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'email'=>'Email Address',
            'firstname'=>'First Name',
            'lastname' => 'Last Name',
                    'verifyPassword' = 'Retype Password'
        );
    }
}
```

Here is my code in my **/views/** folder

```
       $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
            'id'=>'registration-form',
            'type'=>'vertical',
            'enableClientValidation'=>true,
            'clientOptions'=>array(
                'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
            ),
        ));


    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email', array('class' => 'input-block-level', 'placeholder' => 'email')); ?>

            <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password', array('class' => 'input-block-level', 'placeholder' => 'password')); ?>

            <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'verifyPassword', array('class' => 'input-block-level', 'placeholder' => 'verifyPassword')); ?>  


    <?php 
        $profileFields=Profile::getFields();
        if ($profileFields) {
            foreach($profileFields as $field) {

        if ($widgetEdit = $field->widgetEdit($profile)) {
            //echo $widgetEdit;
        } elseif ($field->range) {
            echo $form->dropDownList($profile,$field->varname,Profile::range($field->range),array('class' => 'input-block-level'));
        } elseif ($field->field_type=="TEXT") {
            echo $form->textArea($profile,$field->varname,array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50));
        } else {
            //echo $field->varname;
            if ($field->varname == 'firstname')
            {
                $placeholder = 'First Name';
            }
            else if ($field->varname == 'lastname')
            {
                $placeholder = 'Last Name';
            }
            else 
            {
                $placeholder = $field->varname; 
            }
echo $form->textField($profile,$field->varname,array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>(($field->field_size)?$field->field_size:255),'class' => 'input-block-level', 'placeholder' => $placeholder));
        }

        echo $form->error($profile,$field->varname); 

            }
        }
?>
```

how would i make `attributeLabels()` work on my `echo $form->textField($profile,$field->varname,array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>(($field->field_size)?$field->field_size:255),'class' => 'input-block-level', 'placeholder' => $placeholder));` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to edit `class RegistrationForm extends User`

open **protected/modules/user/model/User.php**

add add/edit your custom labels in the `attributeLabels()` method

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => UserModule::t("Id"),
        'username'=>UserModule::t("username"),
        'password'=>UserModule::t("Password"),
        'verifyPassword'=>UserModule::t("Retype Password"),
        'firstname'=>UserModule::t("First Name"), //ADDED
        'lastname'=>UserModule::t("Last Name"), // ADDED
        'email'=>UserModule::t("Email Address"), //EDITED
        'verifyCode'=>UserModule::t("Verification Code"),
        'activkey' => UserModule::t("Activation Key"),
        'createtime' => UserModule::t("Registration Date"),
        'create_at' => UserModule::t("Registration Date"),
        'lastvisit_at' => UserModule::t("Last Visit"),
        'superuser' => UserModule::t("Superuser"),
        'status' => UserModule::t("Status"),
    );
}
```

and to get the label to show in your view file. use this

```
<?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'verifyPassword',
              array('class' => 'input-block-level', 
             'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('email')));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the text label for the specified attribute with `getAttributeLabel`() like:

```
$model->getAttributeLabel('verifyPassword');
```

E.x:

```
       <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'verifyPassword',
              array('class' => 'input-block-level', 
             'placeholder' => $model->getAttributeLabel('verifyPassword')));
      ?>
```

Comment: @secrettlm  i put that in `class RegistrationForm extends User {` in `models` right?

Comment: i get this `Profile and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "getAttributeLabels". `

Comment: @user2636556: The $model variable you passed from controller to your view do not have getAttributeLabels(). Please define getAttributeLabels() function in your Model class that created $model variable in your view.

Comment: still don't work, gives me `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: @secrettlm  btw, i added this in my model file ` public static function getattributeLabels()
 {
  return array(
   'firstname'=>'First Name',
   'lastname' =>'Last Name',
); }`  and i'm calling it by `$model->getAttributeLabels('firstname')`

Comment: basically i want to set my own custom label

Comment: You should try getAttributeLabel (not getAttributeLAbels), btw getAttributeLabels should not be static.